# Polymer - periodically refresh data from API call

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've written the following custom element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-voltage">
  <template is="auto-binding">
    <div class="circle">{{volts}}</div>
    <div class="circle">{{time}}</div>
  </template>
  <script>
  function httpGet(theUrl)
  {
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); 
      xmlHttp.send( null );
      return xmlHttp.responseText;
  }

    class MyVoltage extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "my-voltage";
      }    
      static get properties() {
        return {
          volts: {
            type: String,
            notify: true,
            reflectToAttribute: true

          },
        }
      }    
      constructor() {
        super();
          var volt = JSON.parse(httpGet('API_call'));
          var voltage = volt.value.toString();
          var ts = volt.timestamp.toString();
          this.volts = voltage;
          this.time = ts;
        }

    }
    customElements.define(MyVoltage.is, MyVoltage);  

  </script>
</dom-module>
```

This gets data via an API call and displays it right on load. However, I need it to refresh data periodically without the user having to reload the whole page. I keep reading through the documentation, but cannot find a solution. Where exactly do I need to put the code to periodically call the API and get new data? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the native `setTimeout`: 
`setTimeout(() => this.someMethod(), 500);`

Also, `<iron-ajax>` will allow you to easily make ajax requests ([docs](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax)).

Example result:

```html
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="shared-styles.html">

<dom-module id="my-voltage">
  <template>
        <iron-ajax id="ajax"
                   auto
                   url="api/call"
                   last-response="{{data}}"
                   on-response="_onResponse"
                   handle-as="json">
        </iron-ajax>
        <div class="circle">[[data.value]]</div>
        <div class="circle">[[data.timestamp]]</div>
    </template>
  <script>
    class MyVoltage extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return "my-voltage";
      }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          data: Object
        };
      }

      _onResponse() {
        setTimeout(() => this.$.ajax.generateRequest(), 5000);
      }
    }
    customElements.define(MyVoltage.is, MyVoltage);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Here, `_onResponse()` gets called after each response, and will create a new request after a 5 seconds (5000 milliseconds) delay.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but doesn't, I'm still trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: (I did replace the api/call with the actual api call)

Comment: I changed the code and added `data` as a property, could you check whether that fixed it?

Comment: I think the only issue was handleAs instead of handle-data and that I forgot an import, otherwise it's perfect, thank you! :)

Comment: Good catch... Updated the answer. You are welcome ;).

Answer (score 0):

Hi XMLHttpRequest is deprecated. You can use the new [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or use the iron-ajax [element](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax) by Google.